# ld: library not found for -lRCTGeolocation error after upgrading to 60.5

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I upgrade my react native project to 60.5 and after that I get this error building iOS 
XcodeSpace

```
ld: library not found for -lRCTGeolocation
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `pod install --repo-update` in your iOS folder.

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation